# Frisby: test that at least one of the fields in an object has the correct data

Tags: json, integration-testing, frisby.js

I need to test with Frisby that at least on of 3 addresses has the data and is not null. Bellow is what is returned currently:

```
  { physicalAddress: null,
  postalAddress: 
   { addressNumber: 1234,
     addressLine1: 'BlaBla 1',
     addressLine2: 'BlaBla',
     addressLine3: null,
     addressLine4: null,
     postalCode: '1234',
     country: 'BlaBla',
    },
  emailAddress: null}
```

I want to write a test that passes if more than one of these address types returns with the correct data.

Something like this: (maybe there is something clever I could put in to replace the '^?^?^', if it was an array I Would have been able to use '?'.

```
.expectJSONTypes('^?^?^', {
    addressNumber: Number,
    addressLine1: String,
    addressLine2: String,
    postalCode: String,
    country: String
})
```

Comment: Now I am using 3 statements like this for each address: " physicalAddress: function(val) { expect(val).toBeTypeOrNull(address.addressTypes); }  ". But this doesn't guarantee that at least one field returns an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easier having a better structured response in which all addresses arrives in an array.

However, for the type of response you get, a solution is to use afterJSON() and jasmine-node matchers as follows:

```
.afterJSON(function(obj){
    expect(obj.addr1 =! null || obj.addr2 =! null || obj.addr3 =! null).toBe(true);
})
```